# How to mock an object that is an input to a function?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Usually when I mock, I have the following type of setup

```
# my_script.py
import numpy as np

def my_func(x):
    out = np.power(x, 2)
    return out
```

then to test the numpy `power` call in `my_script`:

```
# test_myscript.py

import numpy as np
import unittest
import mock

from my_script import my_func


class TestMyScript(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("my_script.np")
    def test_my_func(self, mock_os):
        """Test that numpy.power was called"""
        a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
        my_func(a)
        mock_os.power.assert_called_with(a, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This works fine.

But now if the situation changes, and say I give the `numpy` module as an *argument* into `my_func`; I don't know how to mock `numpy` in this case.

**How would I mock `numpy` in the function below in the same way as it was mocked in `test_myscript` above?**

Note that `numpy` will not be imported in `my_script.py` but will instead be imported in a separate script that runs functions from `my_script.py`.

```
# my_script.py
# numpy NOT imported in this script!

def my_func(x, numpy):
    out = numpy.power(x, 2)
    return out
```

**EDIT:**

Based on @Daniel Roseman's comment, I am including some more code to be explicit on how the functions are called

```
# main_script.py

import numpy as np

from my_script import my_func

def main():
    a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    my_func(a, np)  # numpy is passed into `my_func`
```

Then to test, I am trying the below

```
# test_myscript.py

import numpy as np
import unittest
import mock

from my_script import my_func

class TestMyScript(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("main_script.np")  # import from main_script since numpy is imported here
    def test_my_func(self, mock_os):
        """Test that numpy.power was called"""
        a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
        my_func(a)
        mock_os.power.assert_called_with(a, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But this fails with

```
Ran 1 test in 0.154s
>>> FAILED (failures=1)
>>> AssertionError: Expected 'power' to have been called.
```

Comment: Well, how are you calling this new function in your test? This appears to be dependency injection, the whole point of which is to make it easier to test anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have edited the question to show you how I am calling the functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that using the `unittest.mock.Mock` object here worked best.

So if we have:

```
# my_script.py

def my_func(x, numpy):
    out = numpy.power(x, 2)
    return out
```

Then to test it we have:

```
# test_myscript.py

import numpy as np
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock

from my_script import my_func

numpy_mock = Mock()


class TestMyScript(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_my_func(self):
        """Test that numpy.power was called"""
        a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
        _ = my_func(a, numpy_mock)  # pass the mocked object here
        numpy_mock.power.assert_called_once_with(a, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Which passes the test

Comment: You are right, if you pass your dependency(ies) as argument(s), you can just pass a mock instead, or a faked simpler object to run the test. That's called dependency injection and eases the tests like Daniel said.